# Color stain coming off cutting board

Tags: food-safety, cutting-boards

We received a handmade cutting board as a gift awhile back and I decided to bring it back to life with some Boos board oil and conditioning cream. I noticed when wiping off any excess with a white towel though that the red wood color stain that was used on the board is coming off on the towel.

Does that mean the board is unsafe to prep on? Was it not sealed correctly? Was it the Boos product I used on it?

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to SA!

If the red coloring is wiping off, I personally wouldn't use it for food unless I could contact the maker and find out how they dyed it.  Given that they didn't know enough to seal the dye well enough to keep it from seeping, I wouldn't trust that they knew enough to choose a non-toxic dye.  And while some wood dyes are [non-toxic](https://www.kedadyeinc.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/5384/2018/07/Red-Alcohol-Dye-Liquid.pdf), others are [extremely toxic](https://www.kedadyeinc.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/5384/2018/08/Keda-Amber-Yellow-Dye-Liquid-SDS-1.pdf), even from the same source.